# Does Microsoft Holographic C++ SDK support Oculus and Vive vr devices?

Tags: windows, sdk, virtual-reality, hololens

I'm looking for one reliable SDK for develop my C++ VR application for all popular devices (mainly: Oculus and Vive).
Can I use Microsoft Holographic C++ SDK to support Oculus or Vive devices?